# Nextcloud external login for users in another database

Tags: autologin, owncloud, nextcloud

I have a Nextcloud installation, with users stored in an external database, and this works fine with this app : https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/user_sql

With that in place, I can login on my Nextcloud instance via the login form provided by Nextcloud.

**I need to autolog the users when they come from another app.**

I've written a PHP script, placed at the root of my Nextcloud installation, and it gets called by other internal apps of my company.

This script receives a userId and a token in the URL. After a successful check (no need to get in the details here), **this script should log the user in**.

Which API should I call to get the user logged in?

I tried the following, without success:

- `OC_User::login(...)`
- `OC_User::getUserSession()->login(...)`

Is there a way to trigger a valid login, so that I can get the users logged in?

Thank you for your answers, guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
$user = '';
$pass = '';
$s = \OC::$server->getUserSession();
if (!$s->isLoggedin()) $s->login($user, $pass);
else $s->logout();
```

Placing this at `/index.php` and before calling `OC::handleRequest()` does the trick. It doesn`t work as expected but you could try to continue from here.

PD: `Nextcloud Server v14.0.0 Alpha`

Comment: To be fair... the only I could do was to automatically fill the login fields and to dispatch a click event on the login button with JavaScript